# Default question list

Tags: discussion

We had a discussion on the old meta about the default list of questions.  It looked to me before I logged on that the default list of questions is identical to the old list (and not the weird new one).  Is that so?  If so, great!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, we are using the old active sort on your homepage for anonymous users.

Comment: Thankyou! This is a much better option for the sorts of voting and viewing patterns we get.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's fantastic news.